# ContourPlot3D doesn't even complete after days of running

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I'm using the code

```
ContourPlot3D[
  NumericQ[
    Integrate[
      Piecewise[
        {{Exp[-1/(1 - x^4 - y^4)]*
            Exp[I*ω*10*({Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]} - {Cos[π/2], Sin[π/2]})], 
          Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}, 
        {0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= 1}}, 
        PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], 
      {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]], 
  {ϕ, 0, 2*π}, {θ, 0, 2*π}, {ω, -2, 2}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

I had the parameters set higher before, namely `{x,-10,10}`, etc., and I didn't use the `MaxRecursion` nor `PerformanceGoal`, but after four days of running I still had no result. Even now, I have had it running for most of the day and still no result.

Is this normal?  Can I speed it up?

Edit: Note that the piecewise function I'm trying to plot is:

$$\frac{e^{10i\omega}}{40\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{4}-y^{4}}\right)\exp\left(10i\omega\left(\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos\phi\\\sin\theta
 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos\frac{\pi}{2}\\\sin\frac{\pi}{2}
 \end{pmatrix}\right)\begin{pmatrix}
 x\\y
 \end{pmatrix}\right)\,dx\,dy, \text{ if }\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1\text{ and }0\text{ otherwise}.$$

Comment: The code makes no sense. There are many braces that make no sense where they are. There is a `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` inside `Piecewise`. `NumericQ` doesn't seem to make much sense here either.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Indeed, the `PeformanceGoal->"Speed"` was misplaced in `Piecewise`. And `NumericQ` is there otherwise Mathematica does not perform the integral operation since it has non-numerical values.

Comment: the integrand has non-numerical values because your `Piecewise` function is not correctly built. Read the documentation on how this function is used.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I already read it and I just made the code a bit more efficient by changing it to `Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^4 - y^4)]*
    Exp[I*\[Omega]*10*({Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]]} - {Cos[\[Pi]/2], 
         Sin[\[Pi]/2]})], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}}, 0]`. I think the problem maybe lies with the two dimensional vectors `{Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]]}` and the other one?

Comment: Note that `Cos[π/2] = 0` and `Sin[π/2] = 1` There is no reason not to replace `{Cos[π/2], Sin[π/2]}` by `{0, 1}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has very little to do `ContourPlot3D`. The problem lies in the `Piecewise` expression you are giving `NIntegrate`. It simply doesn't evaluate to a scalar for a large part of its domain. Consider

```
With[{ϕ = 1, θ = 1, ω = 1},
  With[{x = -.5, y = .5}, 
    Piecewise[
      {{Exp[-1/(1 - x^4 - y^4)] Exp[I ω 10 ({Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]} - {0, 1})], 
        Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1},
       {0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= 1}}]]]
```

This returns

> `{0.203152 - 0.245827 I, -0.00462201 - 0.318873 I}`

A list of complex numbers is simply not going to work as the value of an integrand. `NIntegrate` needs a integrand that evaluates to real or complex scalar at each point in its domain. For what you want to do, it had better be a real.

You need to reformulate the expression you are trying integrate.

Comment: When I formulate it like `ContourPlot3D[
 Integrate[
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^4 - y^4)]*
      Exp[I*\[Omega]*10*(x*Cos[\[Phi]] + y*Sin[\[Theta]] - 
          x*Cos[\[Pi]/2] - y*Sin[\[Pi]/2])], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}}, 
   0], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 
  0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Omega], -10, 10}]` I get  the error `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`. Likewise when I use `@Re` before the piecewise expression.